# Python yfinance API: Couldn't fetch data after exception is thrown

Tags: python, yfinance

I encountered a problem when using the yfinance api version == 0.2.33.

Suppose there is a stock which has invalid history (e.g. 0250.HK), and I run this block of code:

```
data = yf.Ticker("0250.HK").history(period="max")
```

then this error will be thrown:

```
Failed to get ticker '0250.HK' reason: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.yahoo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?guccounter=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x125caba60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

The problem is, after this error is thrown, history of valid tickers could not be queried (e.g. 0001.HK). Take the following code as example, after I tried to fetch 0250.HK, querying 0001.HK got the error of:

```
import yfinance as yf

try:
    data = yf.Ticker("0250.HK").history(period="max")
except:
    print("Error")

yf.Ticker("0001.HK").history(period="max")
```

```
0001.HK: No price data found, symbol may be delisted (1d 1925-01-12 -> 2023-12-20)
```

But if I run it independently:

```
yf.Ticker("0001.HK").history(period="max")
```

the price of 0001.HK is returned correctly. How may I solve this error as I have to query data in a for loop? Also, error catching doesn't seem to solve the problem as shown in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

This actually works. You just needed to assign the last line to a variable and print it.

So this works:

```py
import yfinance as yf

try:
    data = yf.Ticker("0250.HK").history(period="max")
except:
    print("Error")

data = yf.Ticker("0001.HK").history(period="max")
print(data)
```

and produces this:

```
0250.HK: No timezone found, symbol may be delisted
                                Open       High        Low      Close    Volume  Dividends  Stock Splits
Date
2000-01-04 00:00:00+08:00  26.740533  27.007940  26.205723  26.205723   3194413        0.0           0.0
2000-01-05 00:00:00+08:00  25.002392  25.403502  24.267030  24.400730   6058531        0.0           0.0
2000-01-06 00:00:00+08:00  24.601294  24.734998  22.729457  23.197416  10440479        0.0           0.0
2000-01-07 00:00:00+08:00  23.531675  23.799080  23.130566  23.665377   6049796        0.0           0.0
2000-01-10 00:00:00+08:00  24.467586  24.868695  23.865925  23.865925   5195404        0.0           0.0
...                              ...        ...        ...        ...       ...        ...           ...
2023-12-13 00:00:00+08:00  39.349998  39.750000  39.200001  39.450001   3389452        0.0           0.0
2023-12-14 00:00:00+08:00  39.500000  40.099998  39.349998  40.049999   9576558        0.0           0.0
2023-12-15 00:00:00+08:00  40.950001  41.700001  40.599998  41.299999  10736226        0.0           0.0
2023-12-18 00:00:00+08:00  41.099998  41.349998  40.700001  41.250000   4587530        0.0           0.0
2023-12-19 00:00:00+08:00  40.799999  41.250000  40.650002  40.950001   2516416        0.0           0.0
```

so you can see that both **the "error" is caught** and **the good data is returned**.

Also, i should point out that there is no error in the `try` block. the return value is an **empty dataframe** so the `except` condition does not run.

Comment: Hello D.L, thank you very much for your reply, by running your example, it still resulted in the same error for me =>
Failed to get ticker '0250.HK' reason: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.yahoo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?guccounter=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x124ed1ea0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
0250.HK: No timezone found, symbol may be delisted
0001.HK: No price data found, symbol may be delisted (1d 1925-01-13 -> 2023-12-20)
Empty DataFrame

Comment: May I ask which version of yfinance api you are using?

Comment: @ecit,  i literally just pip installed `yfinance` to test, so the answer used the latest version which is:  `0.2.33`.

Comment: the important part to note is that `yfinance` never threw an error, it just **returned an empty dataframe** successfully. So, no error is caught.